# React npm warn deprecates how to deal with it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, warnings, deprecated

```
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
tps://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I had same problem and followed below answers, but it didn't work for me. there is any solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue. Just use the following command to update the version of your npm:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Comment: Actually i tried this but then too the error remains the same

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. The only reason it "seems" effective is due to the fact that a second `npm install` doen't show those same warnings, unless you first remove `package-lock.json` (and `node_modules`).

Answer (score 5):

These warnings are coming from the libraries that you are using in package.json. There are 2 types of libraries:

1. Direct library: you are listing it directly
2. Transitive library: that's installed by the usage of other library

So what you have to do:

Run `npm list --depth=3` (increase the depth if you didn't found it)
and track the source of the library, once you found it you have 2 choices:

1. upgrade it, it most cases it works
2. remove it and use another one that have latest versions of transitive libraries

Comment: so how do I perform step 1 'upgrade it'? Do I install it in my package.json or do I update the package's package.json file?

Answer (score 2):

1. Run `npm ls package_name@version`
   so in your case for first package

   `npm ls flatten@1.0.3`
2. You will get the source of its installation. Something like this (for example)

   ```
    │ │   └─┬ webpack@4.46.0
    │ │     └─┬ node-libs-browser@2.2.1
    │ │       └─┬ url@0.11.0
    │ │         └── flatten@1.0.3
   ```
3. So, if it is a direct installation, you can simply find newer version from https://www.npmjs.com. Update the version directly in package.json, remove node_modules folder, and run `npm i`.
4. If it is not a direct installation, you can try updating the parent package in a similar way, and see if it contains updated version of required package. After updating the parent package version in package.json, you will not get error message in terminal, if it contains updated version of outdated package.

This will resolve the error message.

Answer (score -4):

Try

> npm i -g

or

> delete your current version of node and reinstall the latest stable version.

Either of these should work.

Comment: What is this meant to do?